# Repurposing auto cigerette lighter heating element

Tags: voltage, heat, coil

Been trying to solve this and was looking at making custom heating elements with wire but is was getting way too complicated for me. My thought, which would completely solve this assuming I can control how hot it gets somehow. Wanting to use the heating element of a lighter. All I know is cigarette lighters run on 12v DC with a 10 amp fuse. A spring and switch on the arm would start and stop power.

At 12v 10 amp its starts stuff on fire and glows. Thats too hot...

My question is: Can the temp be controlled simply but altering the voltage going to it? Im looking for something around 150 degrees, it would be held in place for X seconds based on the material.

I have no idea where to start doing the calculations etc, and Ive spent hours trying to figure it out...

Any help or direction greatly appreciated.

[[image: demonstration of usage1]

Comment: \$12\:\text{V}\$ and \$10\:\text{A}\$ just means that you are limited to about \$120\:\text{W}\$. Anything below that also works. Watts are just power. They are not heat. You can make something tiny very hot with that. But something large is unlikely to change much in temperature. You'll have to work out the size of the area needing to be softened and its temperature so that the molding is done right. You'll need to work out about how much that area dissipates via convection, conduction, and radiation when at that temperature. Then you can move towards a design if it then passes a basic check.

Comment: Oh. And I missed the fact that you also have to heat up the hand tool. I think a lot more details will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My drawing is horribly out of proportion, the material Im using is .01 and .02", thin stuff and just one second at 150 degrees lets it deflect enough to get the job done. The half dome is only .625", basically the same diameter as the lighter. Currently using a heat gun, but I dont want to heat up such a large area and its complete overkill.

Comment: It's really easy to heat things up. Most of the work here is in designing the handle to be safe while the hot side of the hand tool is just the right temperature to allow your hands the time to press, without burning the material but at the same time softening it at a rate you find works well. Heating elements are cheap and many. Which one is better will depend a LOT on your ability to design that hand tool. I can't help much there. As far as heating it up goes, look into bimetal strips as used in stove burner controls or home heating thermostats. It's really a simple on/off control.

Comment: You will need to ensure that your heating element is itself at least \$12\:\Omega\$, though. More than that if you can get away with it. A higher resistance will use less power. But you absolutely cannot use anything with less than \$12\:\Omega\$. Your goal will be to find a heating element that is that much or more, in resistance, and where your on/off thermostat device is turning on and off about 50% of the time once the device gets up to the right temperature. Plan on some experimentation. If you want a paper design then you will need to provide a LOT of information if it has any chance.

Comment: I have. 10W 12V round LED that would do the job , check out Digikey

Comment: I like the idea of using LED heat source, but Im coing up blank here https://www.digikey.com/. I may not be using the right search term...

Jonk, thanks for the input. This is a basic implementation and goal, the end result will be a more complicated automated process with a machine pushing the arm down so no burns. lol